Issues with CORS and HTTP Requests in Vercel Deployment for Node.js and MongoDB Backend
I'm facing issues with CORS and HTTP requests in my project deployed on Vercel. The project involves a Node.js backend (node-backend.vercel.app) and a frontend (frontend-part.vercel.app). I have defined the necessary routes and CORS configurations in my server.js file and included a vercel.json file in both the frontend and backend.
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin: "https://frontend-part.vercel.app",
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));

// Middleware to set CORS headers for all responses
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://frontend-part.vercel.app");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});

app.post('/stocks/addProduct', (req, res) => {
  // Handle the request
});

client: request are sent as   const response = await axiosInstance.post(https://backend-part.vercel.app/stocks/addProduct, productData);
The problem is that while some requests (GET, POST) work occasionally, other requests fail intermittently. Sometimes, none of the requests work even with minor changes. Specifically, I'm facing an issue with a POST request to /stocks/addProduct.
Here are the 3 different errors  :


This question is similar to: Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
